# Set up the accessibility for UIDocumentMenuViewController

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, testing, uidocumentpickervc

I need to write a UI test that will tap buttons on UIDocumentMenuViewController.

But I can't reach these elements from code because they have not any accessibility like UIView has.

Is there a possible way to get access to options in UIDocumentMenuViewController and set up the accessibility?

Accessibility inspector shows that these elements are not at the appropriate place and traits like static text.

How to fix this?

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this

Comment: impossible - https://twitter.com/joemasilotti/status/645195096602865664